# Page not found when navigating back to the filtered list of jobs

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Go to [jobs tab](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab), open filter and type into the **Tech you like** field, e.g. "Java" (notice capital "J", it is case sensitive to reproduce). Do **not** select technology tag and press **Search** button. Jobs will be displayed for Java technology. Then visit any of the listed job offers and try to return back to the list. You'll get a **Page Not Found** error when redirecting there:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-Java?sort=i

It seems that tags are "picked" only when you use lower case text. Is it possible to "pick" them in the filter automatically case insensitively?

<sup>I'm on up to date Chrome for Android, but I guess it might be irrelevant in this case.</sup>